# пишу код и выскакивает такая ошибка - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'

Tags: python, http

пишу код и выскакивает такая ошибка:

(сам код):

```
from urllib import request

response = request.urlopen('http://example.com')

print(response.status)
print(response.getcode())
print(response.msg)
print(response.reason)
print(response.headers)
print(response.getheaders())
```

(сама ошибка):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Наран\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python project\курсы\python-advanced-materials\001_Работа с сетью\001_Samples\http\example3_urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib import request
  File "C:\Users\Наран\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'
```

Comment: попробуйте написать  **import requests**

Comment: пробовал, но мне как раз таки нужно через urllib, чтобы с помощью функции urlopen запросить url

Answer (score 0):

я понял проблему, она заключалась в названии каталога, в котором находился файл и в названии файла. Нужно просто их переименовать